# ¿Cómo implementar la señal de cambio de fecha en un QDateEdit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Buenas tardes tengo un `QDateEdit` (`self.date`) con la opción de mostrar el `CalendarWidget`. Estoy tratando de implementar la señal para detectar el cambio de fecha pero no funciona este es el código:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from tabla import tabla
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("new_exe.ui",self)


        print(self.date.date().toPyDate())
        self.date.date().connect(self.signal_change)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def signal_change():
        print(self.date.date())



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `date` simplemente retorna la fecha actual del `QDateEdit`, el slot tienes que asociarlo siempre a una señal. En este caso tienes que usar la señal [`dateChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#dateChanged) heredada de `QDateTimeEdit`.

Un ejemplo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class Example(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.date = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self)
        self.date.move(100, 50)   
        self.date.dateChanged.connect(self.on_date_change)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QDate)
    def on_date_change(self, date: QtCore.QDate) -> None:
        print(date)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```